# How to execute a python script with selenium called by php through apache server?

Tags: php, python, html, apache, selenium

I want to execute the following script in Python through my site in local apache server:

```
#!/Python34/python
from selenium import webdriver 
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("C:\wamp64\www\desenvol\index.html")
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_link_text("call another page")
elem1.click()
```

The apache is rightly configured and this is the page that I'm using with the php code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Light Controller</title>
</head>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['LightON']))
{
exec('python hello.py');
echo("on");
}
?>

<form method="post">
<button name="LightON">Light ON</button>&nbsp;
</form> 


</html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting with the current code? Is your Apache user set up for passwordless sudo?

Comment: In truth just the first button matter (Light ON), cause I'm using WAMP. The problem is that nothing happens, the simbol of load appears but the Firefox Browser not open as expected to do.

Comment: You are using WAMP? So do you even have a `sudo` command? What shell are you using?

Comment: I update de code. I'm using CMD-DOS from Windows 10.

Comment: Is `python` on `%PATH%`? What happens when you run the command in a regular command prompt?

Comment: I thing that the problem is that the apache wait until the python script is finished. So I created a python to call another python Script, such:

Comment: import openLink
openLink.run("openLink.py", shell=True)

Comment: Sorry for my bad english skills, i'm Brazilian.

Comment: OH, yes. The programm run very well, but I can't call him through my local web site.

Answer (score 2):

Provide the full path to the python script, i.e.:

```
shell_exec('python /full/path/to/hello.py');
```

If you want to play safe, also provide the full path to the python binary.

```
shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/python /full/path/to/hello.py');
```

To find the full path to the python binary open the shell and type:

```
which python
```

---

1. Make sure the apache user has execute permissions on `hello.py`.
2. I don't see any element with text "*call another page*" on your html.

---

**Update:**

You can also use python's [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html), something like:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import urlparse
class GetHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        parsed_path = urlparse.urlparse(self.path)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        #self.wfile.write(message)
        if (parsed_path.query == "LightON"):
            from selenium import webdriver 
            driver=webdriver.Firefox()
            driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
            elem1 = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Questions")
            elem1.click()
            self.wfile.write("Command Executed")
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
    server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), GetHandler)
    print 'Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop'
    server.serve_forever()
```

---

The above code will open a *webserver* on port `8080`, and wait for a `LightON` request, after receiving it, executes the `selenium` code.

to activate it just create a link to it, something like

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/LightON"> LightON </a>
```

---

PS: I've tested the code and it works as expected.

Comment: didn't work. Cause my problem is too much complicated. In first, use python was a way to solve my problem with Arduino Web Server using ENC28J60 Ethernet LAN Network Module. The python script will enter in the arduino IP (where are: C:\wamp64\www\desenvol\index.html, will be the Arduino local IP) and click in some link... I thing the problem is with the syntax cause I already tried to do a page with python using print (" ") and it worked very well.

Comment: I think you'll have to stop for a bit and think well about what you need, sometimes leaving the computer for while helps. GL.

Comment: My teacher said that I can use Json and jquery to solve my problem insted of use a python script, but the problem is very interesting and I want to find a answer.

Comment: Why don't you use the python  SimpleHTTPServer ? https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

Comment: Out of fun, I've posted the python webserver code demo ;)

Answer (score 0):

I did not solve it in the easy way. So, that is what I do:

- First I created a database with one table and two columns (id and 'numero')
- Then I make a loop in python for take the value from 'numero' in a specific id (0) and to compare if this value is changed, if this happens the python will execute the web driver command
- Finally, I make a php script, inside my html page, to update this value in that specific id(0)

So, that is my code...

### The python final code:

```js
#!/Python34/python  
#from __future__ import print_function #NAO NECESSARIO Estava No exemplo do PyMySQL,aparentemente nao necessario
import time #Importa a função do delay
import pymysql #importa biblioteca para conexao com o python
from selenium import webdriver #biblioteca que me permite acessar o navegador 
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='samsung', db='tccdia')#string de conexao com o MySQL
status = 1 #defina essa variavel para funcionar como uma chave que impede a execução do webdriver assim que o script iniciar 
ValorReferencia = 1 #valor para verificar se o valor do DB foi altera
#chave = 0 #NAO NECESSARIO
while 1<2:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT numero FROM cw_lampada WHERE id = 0")
    result = cur.fetchone()#criei uma variavel para armazenar esse valor porque ele apaga 
    ValorAtual = result
    ValorAtual = ValorAtual[-1] # Tira aspas e virgulas Funcionou mas nao entendi o procedimento
    print ("valor atual: ",ValorAtual," tipo: " ,type(ValorAtual))      
    if status == 1:
        ValorReferencia = ValorAtual
        status = 0
        #chave=1 #NAO NECESSARIO
    print ("valor referencia: ",ValorReferencia," tipo: " ,type(ValorReferencia))       
    #if chave ==1: ##NAO NECESSARIO Maybe this if ins't necessary
    if ValorAtual != ValorReferencia :
        driver=webdriver.Firefox() #Abre o navegador em determinado endereco e abre link
        driver.get("C:\wamp64\www\desenvol\index.html")
        elem1 = driver.find_element_by_link_text("call another page")
        elem1.click()
        driver.close()
        status = 1
        #chave = 0 #NAO NECESSARIO
    cur.close()
    time.sleep(2) #tempo de espera  
#conn.close() #NAO NECESSARIO nao faria sentido ficar abrindo e fechando conexao se o tempo de reconexao eh curto
```

### The MySQL database was something like:

```css
create database tccdia;
use tccdia;
create table cw_lampada(
  id int primary key,
  numero int
);
```

### And the HTML was:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt_BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>lampada</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        require 'config.php';
        require 'connection.php'; #connection deve ser chamado anetes do database
        require 'database.php'; 
    ?>
<form action="" method="post">
         <input type="submit" value="Clicar" name="botao" style="width: 900px; height: 200px;">
    </form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["botao"])){
         echo "botão foi clicado";
         $numero = $numero+1;
             
         $atualizar = array(
                'numero' => $numero
            );                                                                      
        DBUpdate('lampada', $atualizar, 'id=0'); 
    ?>   
</body>
</html>
```

### Of course, there is a more easy and direct way to resolve this, but it is what I did. I hope I have been useful for other with the same problem.